# ANTLR 4 language works when not using it correctly

Tags: java, syntax, antlr

So I built myself a very small and basic programming language with the help of ANTLR 4 and Java. Things works as expected, except my loop statement. In my grammar, I have stated that all statements should be followed by a semicolon (';') when they are typed and my loops execution code should have curly braces. This is what I have in my grammar file:

```
code
:statement ';' code
;

statement
:loop
;

loop
:'när:' expr otherBlock
;


otherBlock
:'('file')'
| code
;

expr
:expr op=('/' | '*') expr              #mullExpr
|expr op=('+' | '-') expr              #addExpr
|expr op=('<='|'>=' | '<' | '>') expr  #relExpr
|atomExpr                              #atom
;

atomExpr
:INT    #numberAtom
|ID     #idAtom
|STR    #stringAtom
;
```

And here is some code to test it(Just a loop which iterates 10 times and adds all the numbers together and then prints the result:

```
variabel index = 0;
variabel nummer = 10;
variabel resultat = 1;

när: index <= nummer
(
    resultat = resultat + index;
    index = index+1;
);

skriv resultat;
```

This gives me the following in my console window:

```
line 9:0 no viable alternative at input ')'
line 12:0 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
resultat=1.0
resultat=2.0
resultat=4.0
resultat=7.0
resultat=11.0
resultat=16.0
resultat=22.0
resultat=29.0
resultat=37.0
resultat=46.0
resultat=56.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, the "skriv" statement(that is my print) executes as if it was inside the loop. Now, if i remove the semicolon after the loop and try running the code again, this is the result:

```
line 9:0 no viable alternative at input ')'
line 11:0 missing ';' at 'skriv'
line 12:0 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
resultat=56.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And that gives me the correct result, but of course it complains that the code is missing a ';'.

Obviously, something is wrong with my syntax, but after hours of trying, I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: `code : statement ';' code;` that rule recurses *indefinitely*. Why don't you use `code: (statement ';')*;` instead? Also, the grammar you posted is obviously incomplete since it only allows loops...

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked, but I'm not sure why. You mean that code makes it call itself forever? Also I omitted code/grammar from the question as I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: I mean that rule would require a second alternative branch to end the recursion. I don't know how ANTLR interpreted that, but as you've seen it didn't do what you intended it to.